# Función que devuelva False para activar de nuevo el input de teclado y ratón

Tags: python, windows

Estoy haciendo un script que bloquea el teclado y el ratón. Como no sabía hacerlo, busqué en la comunidad en inglés de stackoverflow, y encontré [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python). Hay 5 respuestas, pero hay una que necesita permisos de administrador (la podría usar, pero preferiría otra), dos que no hacen lo que busco, y una que no entiendo. La primera me funciona perfectamente, pero tengo un problema, no sé desactivarla. El código es este:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook 

def uMad(event):
    return False

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = uMad
hm.KeyAll = uMad
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Alguien preguntó lo mismo hace años, y le respondieron esto: "You would have to redefine the MouseAll and KeyAll with another function that always returns True. Than the keyboard and mouse would be enabled again."
Seguramente, sea algo muy básico, pero he estado un rato intentándolo y no he podido (soy un principiante). Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Necesito ayuda y nadie me responde :(

Answer (score 0):

Antes que todo fíjese que tiene una devolución de llamada en la función `uMad()` a `False` *(falso)* ya que esto quiere decir que al ser un valor booleano, `False` significa en este contexto deshabilita el mouse y teclado, así que lo que dice en su pregunta, `False` no retorna un valor que rehabite los controladores de teclado y mouse ya que al ejecutar el parámetro `MouseAll` y `KeyAll`, usted llama la función `uMad()` para deshabilitar ambos controladores.

El usuario que responde ahí, lo que quiere decir es que usted debe crear una función que **retorne** a `True` *(verdadero)* específicamente en el parámetro `MouseAll` y otra función para el parámetro `KeyAll` que **retorne** `True`, para rehabilitar ambos controladores.

**Con base en ello, así quedaría:**

```
import pythoncom, pyHook 

def uMad(event):
    return True

def uMad2(event):
    return True

try:
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.MouseAll = uMad
    hm.KeyAll = uMad2
    hm.HookMouse()
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
except: # Aunque no controla la excepción MouseSwitch() 
    pass
```

> Nótese que al usar los bloques `try` y `except`, se intenta controlar excepciones al retornar `True` ya que al investigar, `PyHook` al retornar `True` en `MouseAll` y `KeyAll`  desencadenan un error en el parámetro `MouseSwitch()` en la clase `HookManager` al parecer de un error de identificación de ventana o un error en el control de los eventos en `KeyAll` y `MouseAll`. Es recomendable usar otra librería como `ctypes()` la cual tiene una variedad de funcionalidades para este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Primero, gracias por responder. Lo que quería hacer yo, era primero desactivar input, después añadir más código (por ejemplo un contador), y despúes volver a activar teclado y ratón. Lo intenté redefiniendo MouseAll y KeyAll con una nueva función que devolviera True, pero no se reactivaban. No sé si me expliqué bien...